# How to add to XmlDocument schema from XmlSchema object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api

> > I have problem with add schema to xml document. I added a schema to
> > the document and returning ActionResult I get an xml document without
> > a schema.
> > I defined the schema and added individual elements which I later added to the Xml document
> > How can I fix this problem?

```cs
[HttpGet("ConvertJsonToXML")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public ActionResult ConvertJsonToXML(int? idProjectTlcStairsHistory)
{
    //Find ID
    var result = _project.FindProjectResult(idProjectTlcStairsHistory);
    // Find name project
    var nameProject = _project.ProjectName(idProjectTlcStairsHistory);
    // Change format on improve format
    var fileName = _project.ReplaceInvalidChars(nameProject);
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();              
    string value = o.ToString();
    doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(value, "StairsCalculationsData");
    XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    nameSpace.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
  
    //Schema
    XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
    schema.ElementFormDefault = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified;
    schema.AttributeFormDefault = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified;
    schema.Version = "1.0";
    schema.Namespaces = nameSpace;
    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(schema);
    XmlSchemaElement element = new XmlSchemaElement();
    element.Name = "SpiralStairs";
    element.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("myns:blah", "http://myns.com");
    attr.Value = "my own attribute";
    element.UnhandledAttributes = new XmlAttribute[] { attr };
    schema.Items.Add(element);
   
    doc.Schemas.Add(schema);
    doc.Schemas.Add(schemaSet);
 
    var file = XMLConvert.AddXmlDeclaration(doc);
    doc.LoadXml(file);

    doc.Save(@"C:\Projekty XML\" + fileName + ".xml");
    return Ok(doc);      
}
```

> Result - the result he gets without a schematic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <StairsCalculationsData>
      <centralPipeDiameter>150</centralPipeDiameter>
      <leftTurn>false</leftTurn>
      <rightTurn>true</rightTurn>
      <stairsTurn>-1</stairsTurn>
      <centralPipeHandrail>false</centralPipeHandrail>
      <centralPipeHandrailRadius>120</centralPipeHandrailRadius>
      <radius>1000</radius>
      <walkingWidth>1185</walkingWidth>
      <walkingLineRadius>1000</walkingLineRadius>
      <secondWalkingLineRadius>0</secondWalkingLineRadius>
      <isStandardRadius>true</isStandardRadius>
      <isTlcStandard>true</isTlcStandard>
      <maxStepHeight>240</maxStepHeight>
      <selectedRadius>1300</selectedRadius>
      <selectedStep />
      <levels>
        <levelNumber>0</levelNumber>
        <landing>
          <initialDirection>4</initialDirection>
          <landingShape>0</landingShape>
          <startEdgeHeight>100</startEdgeHeight>
          <endEdgeHeight>100</endEdgeHeight>
          <startLandingAngle>90</startLandingAngle>
          <endLandingAngle>0</endLandingAngle>
          <isLandingAngleProperly>true</isLandingAngleProperly>
          <landingWidth>1570.7963267948965</landingWidth>
          <landingAngle>90</landingAngle>
        </landing>
        <isLastLevel>false</isLastLevel>
        <angleNextLevel>20</angleNextLevel>
        <startFlightAngleFromNextLevel>0</startFlightAngleFromNextLevel>
        <levelMessages />
        <isStepWidthProperly>true</isStepWidthProperly>
        <stepDeepInWalkingLine>347.3</stepDeepInWalkingLine>
        <heightLevel>2750</heightLevel>
        <isStepHeightProperly>false</isStepHeightProperly>
        <stepHeight>114.58333333333333</stepHeight>
        <rotationRange>1.2777777777777777</rotationRange>
        <startFlightAngle>190</startFlightAngle>
        <flightRotationRangeAngle>460</flightRotationRangeAngle>
        <stepAngle>20</stepAngle>
        <isStepsAmountProperly>true</isStepsAmountProperly>
        <stepsAmount>24</stepsAmount>
        <stepsPerTurn>18</stepsPerTurn>
        <isAngleDiffProperly>true</isAngleDiffProperly>
        <angleDiff>0</angleDiff>
        <isConvinienceProperly>false</isConvinienceProperly>
        <convinience>576.47</convinience>
        <isFreeSpaceByHeliceProperly>false</isFreeSpaceByHeliceProperly>
        <endFreeSpaceByHelice>1440.2</endFreeSpaceByHelice>
        <isFreeSpaceProperly>false</isFreeSpaceProperly>
        <endFreeSpace>1504.2</endFreeSpace>
        <isFlightFreeSpaceProperly>false</isFlightFreeSpaceProperly>
        <flightFreeSpace>1847.9</flightFreeSpace>
        <isFreeSpaceAboveLandingsProperly>true</isFreeSpaceAboveLandingsProperly>
        <freeSpaceAboveLandings>2800</freeSpaceAboveLandings>
      </levels>
      
    </StairsCalculationsData>
```

How add to xml information from schema?
Example:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element myns:blah="my own attribute" name="SpiralStairs" type="xsd:string" xmlns:myns="http://myns.com" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: You want to add namespaces to the xml, not a schema.

Comment: I think you might be confused as to what an XML schema is. How do you *want* your XML to look? Please [edit] an example into your question.

Comment: I want add to my xml:  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element myns:blah="my own attribute" name="SpiralStairs" type="xsd:string" xmlns:myns="http://myns.com" />
</xsd:schema>

Comment: As I said, please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: I added to description